# Why is the function with in parenthesis?

Tags: javascript

**Question:**

Why is the function wrapped in a parenthesis? I have taken this code out of parenthesis and it works with no trouble.

What is the benefit of having the code in a (function() { ...Code Here...})(); like it is in the following example?

**Code:**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    // Doesn't work because strict mode 
    // enforces the fact that the second example shouldn't work
    if (true) {
        function fn1() {
            // This won't run
            console.log("doesn't work -- have a great Die Hard Day XIII");
        };
        fn1();
    }
})();
```

Code Here: What would sending the JQuery word as a parameter do for this namespace. I know that the reason that the function is enclosed in (...) is to create a namespace. I guess a better question would be as to why one would pass in a variable, but I would imagine that would be in case another namespace needed the variable.

```
( function( $ ) {
    // Init Skrollr
    var s = skrollr.init({
        render: function(data) {
            //Debugging - Log the current scroll position.
            //console.log(data.curTop);
        }
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: This is called an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) ("iffy")

Comment: I like this question. Even though the other is similar had has good answers I think that this question was as useful for my development of this type of program. I have been wondering this myself. If I am not mistaken it creates a namespace that all other variables can be placed in without another name space using the same variable name and then over writing a variable if there is a chance that two variables my share the same name. A good example would be index or counter or i or j that are used in for-loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have taken this code out of parenthesis and it works with no trouble.

That’s not correct; it can’t run (or even be parsed) by itself. JavaScript sees `function` in a place where a function declaration can be and assumes it’s a function declaration. Parentheses are used to force the context to be an expression. The practice is redundant if it’s unambiguously a function literal – say, in a variable declaration – but many find it more readable. There’s a [jsHint option to enforce it](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#immed), for example.

Comment: For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/Gbnq3/ and open your JS console, and notice the syntax error.

Comment: Ben Alman has a good writeup on it here: [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: I believe that the OP is referring to taking the entire function body out of the `(function () { ... })();` construct, which would make more sense.

Comment: Oh. In that case, @DougHauf: it scopes the `'use strict';` to just that function, which is useful sometimes when you’re not sure that it won’t be poorly combined with other code in a way that either removes strict mode or breaks non-strict-compliant other code.

Answer (score 1):

Because then they are calling it:

```
(function() { ... })();
                    ^^
```

Comment: can you pass parameters into it and then use them in the function?

Comment: I would really add more to this answer. What you have doesn't completely answer the question. Add some examples if you can.

Comment: This is all I know right now.